# Jquery + addClass + dynamic wordpress post id

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I'm looking for assistance on adding a class ('Selected") to a div with a dynamic WordPress post id. When a link is clicked it will jump to the appropriate div which has the id of the WordPress post. How do I get Jquery to find the dynamic div ID of which the anchor is linked to, and add a class to it?

HTML:

```
<a class="jump" href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="content" style="width: ;">
 <div id="132" class="column">Post Div</div>
 <div id="345" class="column">Post Div</div>
 <div id="64" class="column">Post Div</div>
 <div id="22" class="column">Post Div</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('a.jump').click(function(){
$('#22').addClass('selected')
$(element).siblings().removeClass('selected')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.jump').click(function(){

   // this.href will something like  #22, #132... etc

   $('div.content ' + this.href ).addClass('selected');
   $(element).siblings().removeClass('selected')
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no class was added to either the content div, or any of the post divs.